# Stack Overflow keyword not usual

Tags: discussion, technical

You know web page keywords must be:

1. separated by commas (,)
2. put in meta tags

But Stack Overflow does not do it. It does:

1. Separate keywords with spaces
2. Put keywords in a `div` in then body

Why does Stack Overflow do it this way?

Comment: I did a re-write edit to fix your spelling and grammar. I'm a little curious about the answer to this question as well.

Comment: Are you confusing the HTML entity `<meta keywords=..>` with SO's **tags**? Meta keywords are for serach engines (well, [they used to](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)), SO's tag system is independent of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because SO tags are **not** HTML keywords. The latter were created to be used by search engines internal or external to the site but are not visible to end users. But SO tags are fully managed by the StackExchange applications.

What you see in `div` in the body is just a representation of the tags for end users. We need them to easily see how a question has been tagged.

The second part of your question could be rewritten as *Should SE put its own tags in HTML keywords*. As general use search engine like Google already put SO answers in high position when you ask a question about problems with programs and informatic languages, and as they are generally relevant (*), I would say it is just useless.

(*) When I want to search something I often use a Google search and begin with SO answers ... But this is just the way I do :-)